# check user before execute queries

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.1

I want to check the user before execute some queries. I do something like that :

```
DO $do$
  BEGIN
  IF(current_user=$$usrA$$) THEN
    ALTER TYPE enum_to_change ADD VALUE $$myNewValue$$;
  ELSE
    SELECT $$ERROR$$; /*must crash here*/
  END IF;
END $do$;
```

It doesn't work:

```
ERROR:  ALTER TYPE ... ADD cannot be executed from a function or multi-command string
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "ALTER TYPE e ADD VALUE 'myNewValue'"
PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 4 at SQL statement
```

Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: It's a security in sql file. I don't want that other users than userA can execute queries inside the DO statement. I have an error but in french (ALTER TYPE ... ADD ne peut pas être exécuté à partir d'une fonction ou d'une chaîne contenant plusieurs commandes which can be translate as ALTER TYPE .. ADD can't be execute from a function or a chain having several command). It works with an update querie.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/29F36C7C98AB09499B1A209D48EAA615B7653DBCAB%40mail2a.alliedtesting.com

Comment: also, I didn't know that - thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertype.html

> ALTER TYPE ... ADD VALUE (the form that adds a new value to an enum
>   type) cannot be executed inside a transaction block.

https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/3543.1317224437%40sss.pgh.pa.us

> ```
> The comment beside the code says what it breaks:
>
> case T_AlterEnumStmt: /* ALTER TYPE (enum) */
>
> /*
> * We disallow this in transaction blocks, because we can't cope
> * with enum OID values getting into indexes and then having their
> * defining pg_enum entries go away.
> */
> ```

Looks like you can't do it. And it's meant behaviour...